# Problems caused by django quick access interface

Tags: python, django

1.linux django use : gunicorn --timeout 100 --keep-alive 100 -w 2 -b ***.***.***.***:8001 bigfish.apps.bigfish.wsgi &
get 2 process

2.then i click 200/s api:

```
def create(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
     if User.objects.exists(): User.objects.create()
     return Response()
```

3.sometimes create 2 times User object,how to limit 1?

Comment: `if User.objects.exists(): User.objects.create()` So if the user exist, create new User... ?

Comment: Yes, this is just an example! Express the database is created before it is queried, but it will cause data concurrency, and then create 2 data